# jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure-Mysql-Spring-Docker

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm pretty new in spring-boot and I saw and tried solutions to same error but  still getting error building via docker-compose while error is. :

```
2024-02-16T02:15:54.361Z INFO 97 --- [ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-02-16T02:15:59.578Z ERROR 97 --- [ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:175) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
```

I run the mysql in local and try to connect again but still same error. By the way it can connect successfully to a remote database but in local it can not connect. I was working on WSL2 it didn't work than I tried also on Windows machine bu error is same.

Here my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0.28-oracle
    container_name: case-mysqldb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'mysql-db'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    networks:
      - local-network
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - case-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql-db-dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mysql-db-dump.sql:ro
  app:
    image: case-study:1.0
    container_name: case-study
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    networks:
      - local-network
    environment:
      - spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
      - spring.jpa.show-sql=true
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://case-mysqldb:3306/mysql-db
      - spring.datasource.username=user
      - spring.datasource.password=password
      - spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      - spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
      - spring.redis.host=localhost
      - spring.redis.port=6379
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mysqldb

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: my-redis
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    networks:
      - local-network

volumes:
    case-mysql-data:
    redis:

networks:
  local-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.8-eclipse-temurin-17 AS Builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src
RUN mvn clean package


FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=Builder /app/target/*.jar /app/application.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "application.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your application might be trying to connect to the MySQL database service before it's fully started. This is a common issue when working with Docker Compose.  Here's how to address that

- **Health Check:** Implement a health check for the `mysqldb` service. This will ensure your app waits until the database is ready to accept connections.
- **Dependency:** Add `depends_on: mysqldb` to your application's service configuration, along with a condition like `condition: service_healthy`. This forces your app to start only after the database passes its health check.

**Example:**

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  mysqldb:
    ---
    ---
    healthcheck:
      test: mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u $$MYSQL_USER --password=$$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
  app:
    ---
    ---
    depends_on:
      mysqldb:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I add 2 of them, but still got same error. It shouldn't be hard that much I will lose my mind.

Comment: You are right btw. Mysql is not up and running before app the problem is that. But even I add these health check and depends_on it didnt work for me

Comment: @levniko is it the same error or this time are you getting a different one?

Comment: Exactly same error:
2024-02-16T20:29:25.413Z INFO 94 --- [ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-02-16T20:29:30.687Z ERROR 94 --- [ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Comment: okay, can you try change your `spring.datasource.url` to `jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/mysql-db`, note it is service name, not the container name

Comment: Tried, same error. The problem is that I'm profiling mysql container from my local it never running up.

Comment: @levniko can you check by connecting into `mysqldb` container is it running and ping the db container from `app` container?

Comment: sorry I forgot to answer. I checked it and mysql container was not running.